# Checking which user/samaccountname was logged last on one or list of computers

Tags: powershell

Can I somehow check which user/samaccountname was last logged on a list of PCs, if I have the PC names from AD?

I tried:

```
$TargetName = “W7XXXXXXXXXX”
$RC = Get-WinEvent -Computer 
$TargetName -FilterHashtable @{ Logname = ‘Security’; ID = 4672 } -MaxEvents 1 | Select @{ N = ‘User’; E = { $_.Properties[1].Value } }, TimeCreated$RC.Username$RC.TimeCreated
```

Error is Unexpected token -FilterHashtable

Comment: PLEASE ... add code formatting markers around your code. the instructions are linked on the page you used to create your  Question. [*grin*]

Comment: search for the `LogonUI` registry key and grab the value in the `.LastLoggedOnUser`  property. [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

This needs to be on one Line:

```
$RC = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $TargetName -FilterHashtable @{ Logname = ‘Security’; ID = 4672 } -MaxEvents 1 | Select @{ N = ‘User’; E = { $_.Properties[1].Value } }, TimeCreated$RC.Username$RC.TimeCreated
```

or add " ` "

```
$TargetName = "sql01"
$RC = Get-WinEvent -ComputerName `
$TargetName -FilterHashtable @{ Logname = ‘Security’; ID = 4672 } -MaxEvents 1 | Select @{ N = ‘User’; E = { $_.Properties[1].Value } }, TimeCreated$RC.Username$RC.TimeCreated
```